# Use CustomBindings to fade out a DOM element before it is removed by Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Using KnockoutJS Custom Bindings I am trying to fade out a DOM element before it is removed by Knockout.  I have a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PSbKs/47/) that currently behaves as follows when the list selection is changed:

- The old text instantly disappears
- The new text gradually fades in.

However, i would like:

- The old text gradually fades out
- The new text gradually fades in

Is this possible? I can't see a way to operate on DOM elements about to be removed.  The following Update method only fires after they have already been removed (but prior to the new DOM elements being added).

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fade= {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).hide().fadeIn(1500);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to solve it with don't using the `text` binding, instead of your custom `fade` binding should also handle the text additional and removal. With this approach you can hook your fade in/out logic.

So your `fade` binding should look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fade = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) { 
        // initially don't show the element        
        $(element).hide();        
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).fadeOut(500, function() {
            // set the text of the element, 
            // value needs to be defined outside of the fadeOut callback to work
            ko.utils.setTextContent(element, value);
            $(element).fadeIn(500);
        });
    }
};
```

And the usage:

```
<div data-bind="fade: selectedName" class="main"></div>
```

A demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/AwDmC/1/).

Comment: Note that ko.utils.setTextContent(element, value) is not available in Knockouts public api, so does not work in their compressed file, so was not working on our production site. I swapped it out for $(element).text(value) and all is ok now. That only cost me an hour of my life!